# list all image button clicked change image

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

every one ,I am using django's template language with javascript to do "clicked image button change image" ,however,the result I got was only can change the last button.I do not know why what's wrong about the code , here is my

> indext.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
Homepage - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<script>
function setColor(e, btn, color) {
  var target = e.target,
      count = +target.dataset.count;

   target.style.backgroundColor = count === 1 ? "#7FFF00" : '#FFFFFF';
   target.dataset.count = count === 1 ? 0 : 1;
}

  var img_array = [ src="{% static "img/published.png" %}" , src="{% static "img/draft.png" %}"];
  i = 0;

{% for post in posts %}
function myFunction({{ post.model_number }}) {
    i++;
    document.getElementById("{{ post.model_number }}").src = img_array[i];
    if (i == img_array.length - 1) {
        i = -1;

    }

}
{% endfor %}

</script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>產品編號</td><td>產品名稱</td><td>建立日期</td><td>產品圖片</td><td>最後修改日期</td><td>產品說明</td><td>建立者</td><td>修改者</td><td></td>
    </tr>
{% for post in posts %}
    <tr>
        <td> {{ post.model_number }} </td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'thing_detail' slug=post.slug %}">{{ post.name }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ post.created }} </td>
        <td>  <img src="{% if post.image %} {{ post.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}" height="100" width="100"> </td>
        <td>{{ post.modified }} </td>
        <td>{{ post.feature }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.user }}</td>
        <td>{{ post.useredit }}</td>
         {% for cp in post.cataloggroup.all %}
        <td> {{cp }}</td>
         {% endfor %}

        <td><a href="{% url 'edit_thing' slug=post.slug %}"><input class="button0 button2"   type="button" id="button" value="編輯" style="color:#fffff0" onclick="setColor(event, 'button', '#101010')"; data-count="1" /><a></td>



<td><button onclick="myFunction({{ post.model_number }})"><img id="{{ post.model_number }}" src="{% static "img/published.png" %}"    width="50" height="30"></button></td>


</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{% include "pagination.html" with page=posts %}
{% endblock content %}
```

and it will render the web

[image]

however, when I click the top button ,it will change the bottom button,I have to let every button clicked can change image

[image]

above image I clicked top button but changed the bottom button's image "published ---> draft"

[image]

I have to let every button clicked can changed it's own image,how can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the fact you have your `myFunction()` definintion inside a `<script>` tag that is entered into the HTML every iteration of your for loop in django.

This means the function is constantly being redefined and therefore `myfunction` functionality will always be that of the last iteration.

If you define `myFunction()` outside of your django loop and pass in the model number to the function (as below) then it should work as expected`

```js
function myFunction(model_number) {
    i++;
    document.getElementById(model_number).src = img_array[i];
    if (i == img_array.length - 1) {
        i = -1;

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,I just change the code like you say(you can see my source code changed on my question ),but it clicked only still change the down last button's image

Comment: hi, I solve the problem ,according your code,but I adjust a little bit.I just post on the answer,thanks

Comment: Should mark this question as answered for people searching for the same issue in the future

Comment: however,although it can work but , this is not what I want ,because,when I reload the web the image will change back before,I think if I wanna it keep  different image after reload ,I have to do it on back-end,do you know any example for the front button clicked change image forever even reload the web? thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok,I solve the problem

> index.html

```
<script>   
...........  
var img_array = [ src="{% static "img/published.png" %}" , src="{% static "img/draft.png" %}"];
  i = 0;


{% for post in posts %}
function a{{ post.model_number }}() {
    i++;
    document.getElementById("{{ post.model_number }}").src = img_array[i];
    if (i == img_array.length - 1) {
        i = -1;

    }

}

{% endfor %}

</script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>

{% for post in posts %}
    <tr>
    .........    

<td><button onclick="a{{ post.model_number }}()"><img id="{{ post.model_number }}" src="{% static "img/published.png" %}"    width="50" height="30"></button></td>


</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```